# TensorFlow Gradient Tape - LookupError (Tandem Neural Network project)

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, cost-function

I am trying to train a network by using a custom lost function, then computing the gradient of the loss, and updating the trainable variables in the reverse network (named: reverse_loaded).

For finding the gradient, I am using GradientTape, but not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
# Define the loss function
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)

import keras.losses
keras.losses.custom_loss = custom_loss

#Define function that pass input through the reverse network, and then the forward network, and then find loss values
def pass_through(norm_train_X_rev):

    # Pass the inputs through the reverse network
    output_rev = reverse_loaded.predict(norm_train_X_rev) #<- This line raises the error
    np_output_rev = np.squeeze(np.asarray(output_rev))

    # Pass the outputs of the reverse network as inputs to the forward network
    output_forw = forward_loaded.predict(np_output_rev.transpose())
    np_output_forw = np.squeeze(np.asarray(output_forw))

    loss_value = custom_loss(norm_train_X_rev, np_output_forw.transpose())
    return (loss_value)


num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Pass through and get loss
   
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(reverse_loaded.trainable_variables)

        # Calculate the loss
        loss_value = pass_through(norm_train_X_rev)

        # Backward pass and compute the gradients
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, reverse_loaded.trainable_variables)

    # Update the parameters of the reverse network
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, reverse_loaded.trainable_variables))

    # Empty optimizer loop again before the next iteration (?)

    print('epoch =', epoch)  # Tracking
    print(loss_value)
```

### Here is the error I got:

```
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-66883448ccb6> in <cell line: 27>()
     34         # Calculate the loss
     35         #loss_value = custom_loss(norm_train_X_rev, np_output_forw.transpose())
---> 36         loss_value = pass_through(norm_train_X_rev)
     37 
     38         # Backward pass and compute the gradients

2 frames
<ipython-input-82-66883448ccb6> in pass_through(norm_train_X_rev)
     13 
     14     # Pass the inputs through the reverse network
---> 15     output_rev = tf.stop_gradient(reverse_loaded.predict(norm_train_X_rev))
     16     np_output_rev = np.squeeze(np.asarray(output_rev))
     17 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    637               grad_fn = func_call.python_grad_func
    638             else:
--> 639               raise LookupError(
    640                   "No gradient defined for operation"
    641                   f"'{op.name}' (op type: {op.type}). "

LookupError: No gradient defined for operation'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext). In general every operation must have an associated `@tf.RegisterGradient` for correct autodiff, which this op is lacking. If you want to pretend this operation is a constant in your program, you may insert `tf.stop_gradient`. This can be useful to silence the error in cases where you know gradients are not needed, e.g. the forward pass of tf.custom_gradient. Please see more details in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient.
```

Note that the error is raised on the line:

```
output_rev = reverse_loaded.predict(norm_train_X_rev)
```

For troubleshooting, I tried to move the GradientTape to only enclosing the loss calculation, such as:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(reverse_loaded.trainable_variables)

        loss_value = loss_value = custom_loss(norm_train_X_rev, np_output_forw.transpose())

        # Backward pass and compute the gradients
gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, reverse_loaded.trainable_variables)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, reverse_loaded.trainable_variables))
```

But then, I got gradients = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Any suggestions or solutions are greatly appreciated!